# Error at ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate - XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm following this [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1) about accessing the contact list. 
But I`m getting an error on the following line at ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Why ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is getting an error?
The error message is "Cannot find protocol declaration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

to the .h file and add the `AddressBookUI` framework to your project.